# How are formatters in CoC configured?

Tags: neovim, formatting, plugin-coc

I have been using CoC for a few weeks now and I quite like it. Recently I started configuring the formatting options. I have put `"coc.preferences.formatOnSave": true` and configured `.clang-format` file inside my CPP project. Everything worked out of the box and my files were nicely formatted on each save.

I ran into a problem when I wanted to use a feature of `clang-format-13` and the default version of `clang-format` on my system is 11. I looked throughout the CoC wiki and configuration options, and I couldn't find where exactly is the formatter command specified? I guess that running `clang-format` is a default option for cpp filetypes and that is why it worked out of the box, but I would like to change it so that `clang-format-13` is run on each save.

Note: I know I could just symlink `clang-format` to `clang-format-13`, but I would like to know how is this handled by CoC under the hood.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Nope, soon after I ran into this issue I decided to try out neovim (unrelated to this problem) and I used its builtin lsp system, so I'm not using CoC anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting options may be specific per LSP. For example, `haskell-language-server` expects the formatter options to be set like this in your `:CocConfig`:

```json
{
    "languageserver": {
        "haskell": {
            "command": "haskell-language-server-wrapper",
            "args": ["--lsp"],
            "rootPatterns": ["*.cabal", "stack.yaml", "cabal.project", "package.yaml", "hie.yaml"],
            "filetypes": ["haskell", "lhaskell"],
            "settings": {
                "formattingProvider": "fourmolu",
                "plugin" : {
                    "fourmolu" :{
                        "config": {
                            "external": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```